# Ruby connecting to external Mongo DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, mongodb

We have a main portal site (running Rails 4 with a PostgreSQL database), and an external image server (running Node.js with Mongo database). I'm trying to establish a connection from Rails to the database - I installed the mongo gem - https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/ruby/ - and have been following the guide, but got stuck on an odd key error that I can't seem to find any information on.

The image server itself is running fine with no problems (it has a GUI interface that is working fine).

In my controller (I changed the names and left out the passwords):

```
image_server = Mongo::Client.new([ 'image.companyname.com:####' ], :database => 'db-name')
```

It seems to connect:

```
D, [2015-11-11T00:41:22.730360 #9410] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Adding image.companyname.com:#### to the cluster.
```

But then just spams this message over and over (and queries don't do anything but return this error even faster).

```
D, [2015-11-11T00:41:22.991386 #9410] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | key not found: "t"
```

Eventually it returns one error message as well, but keeps spamming the key not found error as well:

```
Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable (No server is available matching preference: #<Mongo::ServerSelector::Primary:0x007f5a943f6ee8 @options={"mode"=>:primary, "database"=>"db-name"}, @tag_sets=[], @server_selection_timeout=30>):
```

app/controllers/admin/model_controller.rb:9:in `index'

EDIT
I even tried connect directly to the UNIX socket, and got the same error:

```
image_server = Mongo::Client.new('mongodb://image.companyname.com:####/path/to/socket/socketname.sock')
```

END EDIT

I'm unsure what the heck this 'key not found "t"' error is, or how to even begin to diagnose this. I've messed with every single connection option I can think of, and nothing changes. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you querying?

Comment: My query test was just `temp = analysis_server.database_names` (I've tried other things too) - none of it actually returns anything, it just spams the 'key not found "t"' error even faster if I try anything, like each attempt starts generating the error.